Kitchen drain height issue
Is the height of my drain going into the wall too high and I’m screwed? What should I do?

Or this? Can the garbage disposal outlet be lower than the building drain inlet?

Or this? Disposal pipe level or slightly below stub out

Or even Is it ok that a new deeper sink disposal line is the same height as drain line? or Drain and disposal outlet same height??

Yes with a drain at that height you will always have water in your disposal.
Either go without a disposal, or have the drain lowered.
A last suggestion that is probably the least popular, is a sink that is not so deep.
I know of no disposal that has a discharge port that high on the unit.

There are the sinks with a smaller, shallower bowl for the disposal so it ends up at similar height to a drain from the regular depth sink. But of course this problem usually comes after choosing a massively deeper sink in a remodel that the homeowner wants, so lowering the drain in the wall is the best option to preserve that presumably new purchase.
